# Mathematical modeling of low-temp plasma

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

I am working on a heavily mathematically project about plasma. In particular, I want to find references that treat the problem from microscopic models that include relativistic and magnetic effects (Coulomb forces, QFT, etc) and obtain kinetic models (BBGKY, Landau equation, Maxwells equation, etc). What are some state of the art papers/references?

Comment: Do you mean Vlasov and/or PIC simulations?

Comment: Not simulations, more like derivation of kinetic equations like Vlasov or Landau from perturbative microscopic models

Comment: Well Vlasov is okay but most plasmas have some level of collisions, even if small... BBGKY is good too...